# Get reviews in an incremental order - Trustpilot

Tags: trustpilot

I want to get reviews using Trustpilot APIs. I know that I can do one time fetch by using **page** parameter to get all reviews.

But is there a way to **filter on a date**? I would like to run my script to fetch the reviews after a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming trustpilot has the date in the API, what you can do is quite simple.
Create a new empty list for the reviews that you wish to show. The convert the date you want the reviews you want the reviews after to a millisecond/seconds date. Then proceed to loop through the reviews, and if the date converted to millisecond/seconds is greater than the one you want, append it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter `startDateTime` when you are getting private reviews for your own business:
https://documentation-apidocumentation.trustpilot.com/business-units-api#business-unit-private-reviews

In this case add the following to the endpoint:
`?startDateTime=2013-09-07`

However, the parameter `startDateTime` is not available for the public reviews:
[https://documentation-apidocumentation.trustpilot.com/business-units-api#get-a-business-unit's-reviews](https://documentation-apidocumentation.trustpilot.com/business-units-api#get-a-business-unit%27s-reviews)

In that case you would first have to get all public reviews and then filter out afterwards using python/javascript/etc.